# Does dropping a computer cause the pictures on it to lose quality?

Tags: image-quality, macbook

After dropping my MacBook, the pictures on it have become pixelated.

Comment: Does the display on your MacBook exhibit any problems (color issues, inability to go to highest resolution, etc.)?

Comment: Actually you should have given more details: What software does show that effect? Does your MacBook have a disk or an SSD?

Comment: Can you please post an example?

Comment: vtc b/c It's bad enough we entertain "I dropped my camera" and "I dropped my lens" questions.   Now we're on to "I dropped my computer" questions?  Have you considered bringing your computer to an Apple Store for help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It about diagnosing a malfunctioning computer after it has been dropped.

Comment: This is just the latest in a series of "After [insert bizarre & unrelated coincidence here] my pictures are pixellated" questions from the same OP.

Comment: @Tetsujin What if the computer is actually an Etch-A-Sketch ?

Comment: Obviously we need to stop answering your questions because you never provide any feedback to users who try to help + your questions are **always** too broad, and **never** include any example of the issue. I also believe you are not facing all the issues you describe in your numerous questions and therefore wonder why you ask them at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can drop computers or tablets that contain digital files and it is unlikely that these files would be harmed. More likely, the display board or screen has been harmed. You should attempt to transfer these image files to another computer or storage media. Next examine these images on another device. If you succeed with this transfer, I believe the images will then display with the same quality as before.

Answer (score 3):

It is *incredibly* improbable that physical damage to your computer only seems to affect one type of file (such as images), without causing other noticeable issues (such as general data loss, problems even booting, etc.). I'd go so far as to say it's even statistically impossible.

Now, it's *slightly* more possible that a certain few files that you might have been working on or editing at the time of the damage are problematic. But even then, you'd probably have more general data corruption problems with those files, rather than just pixelation / lower resolution. Experiencing pixelation would mean the image files and data would somehow have lost information but in a logical, correctly-parseable way. From an entropy standpoint, that just won't happen. The analogy would be to take a random deck of cards, throw it on the ground, and all of the face cards get kicked out and the remaining cards stay in the same order without scattering all over the place. Simply—ain't gonna happen.

Comment: It might be possible that a raw file was corrupted and now whatever application is being used is displaying a much lower resolution embedded thumbnail for the corrupted image(s).

Comment: @MichaelC entirely possible. But not very likely that just raw files were corrupted and nothing (apparently) else.

Comment: Maybe he hasn't really looked at "everything else" yet, or maybe it was a folder of files that were currently being worked on? Just a possibility.

Comment: @MichaelC yeah, I was sort of alluding to that in my 2nd paragraph.